# CSS tooltip with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain to me how to modify the hover tooltips found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) so that they dynamically scale to the length of the text they contain? I have found several tutorials regarding this and literally none of them seem applicable to this specific use case. I'm losing my mind here, I just cannot get this to work.